# Firebase permission denied when attempting to load only records tagged as "public"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userShaders": {
      "$uid": {
        "shaders": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
          ".read": "auth.uid === $uid || data.child('public').val() == true"
        }        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My data looks like this:

```
userShaders
  8v4N3yLlXAU1cpRiaDj5kkDQaKn1
    shaders
      myShaderName
        attr_1: ""
        attr_2: ""
        public: false
```

I am *not* logged in as this user and am attempting to query their data. I expect to *succesfully* get back 0 records because they have none marked as `public`.

However, I'm getting a permission denied error.

My query looks like this:

```
val shaderRef = db
 .getReference("userShaders/${uid}/shaders")
 .orderByChild("public")
 .equalTo(true);

shaderRef.get().addOnSuccessListener {
 // do something with the data
}
```

To summarize, I am trying to query for *only* public data, while simultaneously making a rule that non-public data is impossible to fetch by other users. I want to write a query such that I may receive 0 or many records back, but never a permission denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to realize is that Firebase [security rules don't filer data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters). Instead they merely check that you're only requesting data you are authorized for.

Your code already queries only for the public data, so you need to [validate that query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) in your rules with something like:

```
"shaders": {
  ".read": "query.orderByChild === 'public' &&
            query.equalTo === true"
}
```

Even with that you will still need separate read operations for the shared that this user created and all public shaders, as there's no way to express that OR condition in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up just separating my data into separate `public` and `private` sections in Firebase like this:

```
    "userShaders": {
      "$uid": {
        "shaders": {
          "public": {
            ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
            ".read": "true"            
          },
          "private": {
            ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
            ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"            
          },            
        }        
      }
    }
```

It's more work, because when I update the `isPrivate` boolean I have to make sure to delete it from the other section, but it does get the job done.

Open to other answers if there's another way to do this.